# Universal Links to open the application or the browser

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I am trying to have exclusion on the universal links depending of some flows to the user we want to open sometimes the application or sometimes the browser

those are examples of the url

https://www.myfakedomain.com/page1 **(Should open the app)**

https://www.myfakedomain.net/page1#no_universal_link  **(Should open the browser)**

For this we check the video for the [WWDC 2019 What's New in Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/717/?time=508)

and we create the app associated domain file in this way

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "XX00XXXX00.com.mydomain.myapp",
                "paths": [
                    "NOT /page2/*",
                    "*"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "#": "no_universal_link",
                        "exclude": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

(We also added some paths that should be always ignored)

After applying this changes the all the universal links now open on the browser

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some helpful advices to debug associated domains:

1. Your bundle id should include associated-domains entitlement;
2. Make sure your link for associated domains (provided in Signing & Capabilities -> Associated Domains capability -> "applinks:test.com" for example) is VALID. You can use branch.io validator (https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/);
3. Make sure your JSON file with applinks:

- is a plain text file with no extension.
- uncompressed size of the apple-app-site-association file must be no greater than 128 KB, regardless of whether the file is signed.
- file has valid format.
- file upload it to the root of your HTTPS web server or to the .well-known subdirectory.

4. You should implement application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler: method in AppDelegate.

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html;

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes the JSON file is working, if I remove the part of components, the Universal Links works well, but is that exclusion of #no_universal_link what is causing troubles